# Encapsulation, getter returns null or 0

Tags: java, encapsulation

I'm stuck on encapsulation. It seems to me as if I did everything by the rules and it still doesn't work. Though I know I'm missing something. I'm working with Eclipse.

I wanted some practice by creating a deck of standard 52 cards and experiment with new things I've learned. I've made a Card class inside a deckOfCard package:

```
package deckOfCards;

public class Card {

    private int value;
    private String name;

    public void setName(String n){
        n = name;
    }   
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setValue(int v){
        v = value;
    }
    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then I've made a class with main called Deck where I made all the 52 cards (I'm sure there's easy and faster way, but I'm not there yet)

```
package deckOfCards;

public class Deck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Card h1 = new Card();
        h1.setValue(13);
        h1.setName("Ace of Hearts");

        Card h2 = new Card();
        h2.setValue(1);
        h2.setName("Two of Hearts");
.
.
all the way to
.
.

        Card d12 = new Card();
        d12.setValue(11);
        d12.setName("Queen of Diamonds");

        Card d13 = new Card();
        d13.setValue(12);
        d13.setName("King of Diamonds");
```

but when I try to outprint any value or name (System.out.println(h1.getName()) or System.out.println(h1.getValue())) in the Deck class of any card I get null (string) or 0 (int) as if I didn't set either.

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private String name;

public void setName(String n){
    n = name;
}
```

You're overwriting the local (`n`) with the class var (`name`). swap them (`name = n`).